# Patterns in square root whole numbers

Tags: square-numbers

I am working with kids who discovered a pattern in squaring numbers and want to know why that is and is there a way of showing it as a formula and visually.
The pattern is this:
1 squared is 1,
4 squared is 2,
9 squared is 3,
16 squared is 4,
The pattern related to the number being squared and that it increased in a pattern of +3, +5, +7, and continues.  Can you explain why?

Comment: Not squared. "Square-rooted"

Comment: Consider $(n+1)^2 - n^2$... The first can expand as $n^2+2n+1$.  So... $(n+1)^2-n^2 = (n^2+2n+1)-n^2 = 2n+1$ which is precisely the pattern that you noted.

Comment: Indeed in the reference just given, the graphical explanation by Larry Wang in very understandable by kids.